# in git hub when i am trying to push the files ,i am facing below mentioned issues

Tags: git, github

```
The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream https://github.com/vinaykumarsp/vinaysp master

To have this happen automatically for branches without a tracking
upstream, see 'push.autoSetupRemote' in 'git help config'.
```

Comment: So, what happened when you tried the recommendations that Git printed? Side note: you do not push *files*, with Git; you push *commits* (which then contain files, but its a package deal: you either push a commit and *all* of its files, or you don't push the commit, and don't get any of its files). Other side note: this is a comment about *improving your question*, it's not an answer.

Comment: Your repo is public and has four commits already, so how did they get there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Git's advice here is, unfortunately, wrong.  In particular:

> ```
> git push --set-upstream https://github.com/vinaykumarsp/vinaysp master
> ```

is not going to work because `https://github.com/vinaykumarsp/vinaysp` is a *URL* rather than a *remote*.

A *remote*, in Git, is a short name like `origin` whose main job is to store a URL for you.  When you first clone some Git repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Git sets up an initial remote for you named `origin`.  Most users never add any additional remotes to such repositories, so that they have one remote named `origin` which is the (one) correct remote to use all the time.

If you do have a remote named `origin` that stores the URL `https://github.com/vinaykumarsp/vinaysp`, you really want:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

here.